# Element wise operations on nested tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

Element-wise addition of tuples is fairly straightforward:

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
b = (2,4,6,8)
tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(a,b))

(3,6,9,12)
```

But element-wise addition with nested tuples is more complicated:

```
a = ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
b = ((2,4),(6,8),(10,12))
tuple(x+y for tup_a, tup_b in zip(a,b) for x,y in zip(tup_a,tup_b))

(3,6,9,12,15,18)
```

The tuple is flattened.  How can I perform element-wise addition on nusted tuples while preserving the structure of the tuple?

This is the desired output:

```
((3,6),(9,12),(15,18))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the generator expressions:

```
tuple(tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(tup_a, tup_b)) for tup_a, tup_b in zip(a, b))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
>>> b = ((2,4),(6,8),(10,12))
>>> tuple(tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(tup_a, tup_b)) for tup_a, tup_b in zip(a, b))
((3, 6), (9, 12), (15, 18))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def xsum(a,b):
    if isinstance(a,(list,tuple)) and isinstance(b,(list,tuple)):
       return [xsum(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
    return a+b

a = ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
b = ((2,4),(6,8),(10,12))
print [xsum(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

is probably what I would do, this should work for more levels of depth than just two also